# Shell color theme vs Terminal theme

Tags: command-line, themes, gnome-terminal

Could someone explain how terminal and shell work in terms of theming? Shell frameworks, like oh my zsh, allow you to change color theme. However, terminal emulators, like Blackbox, also allow you to change colors.

How does it work? Don’t these two ways to configure theme conflict with each other?
Is there any good resource that explains how it actually works?

Comment: Not focsued on colors, but this is useful reading: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126). That said I doubt there will be a general answer for all terminal emulators. Can you focus o a specific one?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755974/53656